# Can't get full process.argv list when passing custom arguments to jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, argv

Suppose I have 2 test files below in `__test__` folder

```
====
argv1.test.js
console.log("process.argv1 = ", process.argv)
====
argv2.test.js
console.log("process.argv2 = ", process.argv)
====
```

If I run `npx jest argv1`, it's OK to get full arguments

```
process.argv1 =  [
      'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
      'D:\\work\\git\\nodenewman\\node_modules\\jest\\bin\\jest.js',
      'argv1'
    ]
```

The same happens to `npx jest argv2`

```
process.argv2 =  [
      'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
      'D:\\work\\git\\nodenewman\\node_modules\\jest\\bin\\jest.js',
      'argv2'
    ]
```

But if I run `npx jest argv` to run all argv*** test files then I can't get full arguments anymore, the 3rd argument went away and the 2nd argument is also changed from jest.js to processChild.js

```
 process.argv1 =  [
        'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
        'D:\\work\\git\\nodenewman\\node_modules\\jest-worker\\build\\workers\\processChild.js'
      ]

 process.argv2 =  [
        'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
        'D:\\work\\git\\nodenewman\\node_modules\\jest-worker\\build\\workers\\processChild.js'
      ]
```

Is there any ways to get full arguments in case of running command `npx jest argv` to run all matching argv*** test files?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the result of using the CLI option `--testPathPattern` ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testpathpatternregex)), as in `npx jest --testPathPattern argv` would give a similar result to the commands you are running and would have a more consistent `process.argv`.

Comment: Thank @76484. I also post my work around solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around solution for this question, with this jest will run with `jest.js` instead of `processChild.js` then we can get all arguments. Share here for everyone, hope this helps.

```
//add this line to file jest.config.js    
maxWorkers: 1,
```